# Symfony2 form type with collection field of same type (hierarchy)

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

How can you have a form type with a collection field of the same form type embedded inside it? I've got the following form type within my Symfony 2 project:

```
class MenuType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('label')
            ->add('uri')
            // the following does not work
            ->add('children', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new MenuType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Mango\CoreDomain\Model\Menu',
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'cascade_validation' => true
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'menu';
    }
}
```

When you run this, it will not work. How would something like this be solved in a clean way?

The class that this form type uses is called `Menu` and has a property `children` which is an array of `Menu` objects.

Thanks!

Comment: try with `->add('children');` Can you show how do you define `children` in your entity?

Comment: The object ```Menu``` has a property children which is an array of ```Menu``` objects.

Comment: Does it look like:
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Menu")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="menu_children",
     *  joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="menu_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *  inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="child_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $children;?

Comment: I am using PHPCR-ODM, but yes it would look something like that. Also ```->add('children')``` does not work, because the form builder does not know how to build (there is no type defined) an entry inside ```children```.